# Is there anybody using 2x Client?

Tags: remote, client

I need to use the app: 2X Client for work. I can get it to work, make connection to the server and work with it but as soon as I open the terminal screen it goes full screen and the only thing I can do is log out to get back to my desktop! There's no other way for me at this point.

I come from a windows environment and there's a so called connection-bar on top of the screen where I can minimize/window the terminal screen so I can work with the Ubuntu desktop. This bar is missing with my.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set up display size in properties for your remote desktop connection.

Open Connection Properties for your connection to remote server -> Display -> General Options -> Size and select size you want.

Comment: Thanks,for your answer. Unfortunately I cannot change this setting. The only thing I can Change is the color dept. Perhaps thereś another way to change this, in a configuration file maybe???

Comment: which version of  2X Client do you have?

Answer (score -1):

@user187631: Same problem here.
Tip from my colleagues: use Windows key + (left) Alt key + M to minimize your window (and access your local desktop).

For myself, also being unable to set my own preferred screen size, I found unchecking 'Span desktop across all monitors' somewhat helpful too (Connection Properties -> Display -> Desktop Options). Using version 10.5 (build 1359).